# Exporting Hash to csv - first row as hash key and subsequent as hash values

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

How can I output the contents of a hash to excel/csv with the key as the first row and the values in the subsequent rows? I have the following, but it is not efficient since I open the csv multiple times.

```
rowid = -1
CSV.open("file.csv", 'a') do |csv|
  details.each do |hsh|
    rowid += 1
    if rowid == 0
      csv << hsh.keys# adding header row (column labels)
    else
      csv << hsh.values
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "not efficient since I open the csv multiple times". Your loop seems to be inside the csv open block, which is executed only once.

Comment: The whole block is inside another loop. But come to think of it, i have no choice but to open the csv multiple times. Sorry for an incorrect question and thanks for pointing out! Regards

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention that the `CSV` class gives you the ability to write headers as such:

```
columns = details[inner_hash].keys.to_a
CSV.open('test.csv', 'w', write_headers: true, headers: columns) do |csv|
  #logic in here
end
```